# How to handle delay in jmeter based on response code

Tags: timer, jmeter, beanshell

My requirement was that whenever there was an error in the Jmeter execution, there should be a delay before starting the next iteration.

"Start Next Thread Loop" is selected at the Thread Group level for Sampler error. Due to this Jmeter will start a new Iteration if there is any error during the execution.

For this purpose I have used Beanshell Timer at the start of the Iteration. Following code is added for delay if the response code is anything other than "200"

```
String code = prev.getResponseCode();
if(code!="200"){
log.info("::::::::::::::::::::::::::::Response Code = "+code);
log.info("sleep for 10sec");
 return 10000;
}
else
 return 0;
```

Please let me know if there are any better ways of doing this.

I believe the prev.getResponseCode() can also be used to do any kind of cleanup task, in case there is any error.

Like for example, if a user logs into the application and got an error before doing logout. We can test at the start of the iteration if the previous response code is in error, if so, we can make the user logout of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using:

- [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) that will check if last response was in error or not using

> ${__jexl2("${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}" == "false",)}

[image]

- [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) that will be used to Start Next Thread Loop

[image]

Test plan would have the following layout:

[image]

Comment: You solution is correct. I have tested the same with some sample scripts. I have also up-voted your solution. 
The thing is that I wanted to keep it open, in case any one had any other solution. 

I have another question on the error handling on the start of the script. As per my requirement, If there was any error in the script execution, the next iteration should logout the user and sleep for some random time, before continuing with normal execution. What happens if we clear the cache at the start of each iteration?

Comment: Hi, you should open another question and clarify a bit more your requirement. Regarding answer acceptance usually after few days you shoudn't get any more answer but you always have the possibility to unaccept an answer if a better one is given